# Inkscape text with inconsistent line height

Tags: inkscape, text

I often have the problem in Inkscape that text has an inconsistent line height. Example below:

[image: Different line height in text field]

The gif below shows my problem while I'm adding [enter] to the text:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably didnt its just that you made a paragraph change and you may have paragraph spacing in your style. Instead of try doing *shift* + *enter* as this makes a line break not a paragraph break. WHich is the correct thing to do. This is not a typewriter after all.

Comment: Thanks for replying! So i need to make sure to always do [enter] instead of [shift+enter]?

Comment: No in this case you should do shift + enter. Because your only wanting to break the line.

Comment: Oooh. [shift + enter] = line break, [enter] = paragraph break

Answer (score 3):

This isn't caused by paragraph styles, because Inkscape has no paragraph styles or paragraph spacing.  Inkscape has rather primitive text handling capabilities, unlike word processor or page layout software.

It's likely caused by some of the text having a different baseline spacing setting from other parts of the text. You may have done this accidentally. You may not be able to easily find out which part of the text has different formatting.

The easiest way to fix it is to click inside the text box with the text tool. Select all the text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then type a new baseline spacing value in the control bar along the top. That should reset all the text to have the same spacing.
[image]